# Angular 4 Components not being filled horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, width

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8yZe.png)
So I wanted the image and the navbar text to fill the entire screen horizontally, but can't find a way to do it.  I have used CSS properties border padding and width to try and expand the background the navbar elements, but nothing seems to change it; the elements always remain centered with borders.

This only happens after I transition my code from HTML/CSS to Angular; this is how my code looks when I don't put it in components:

Does anyone know how to fix this? thanks in advance

[Components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8yZe.png)

```
content_component.html <!-- Intro Header -->
<div class="all">
<header class="masthead">
  <div class="intro-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle js-scroll-trigger">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

  <!-- About Section -->
  <section id="about" class="content-section text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <h2>About Me</h2>
          <p>
            hello
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

content_component.css
    .all{
      height:100%;
      background: black;
      color: white;
      margin: 0;

    }

    .masthead{
      display: table;

      overflow:auto;
      padding-left: 0px;
      padding-right: 0px;
      padding-top: 100px;
      padding-bottom: 600px;

      text-align: center;

      color: white;
      background: url('../../img/intro-bg.jpg') no-repeat bottom center scroll;
      background-size: 100%;
      background-color: black;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      .intro-body {
        display: table-cell;

        vertical-align: middle;
        .brand-heading {
          font-size: 50px;
        }
        .intro-text {
          font-size: 18px;
        }
      }
      @media(min-width:768px) {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        .intro-body {
          .brand-heading {
            font-size: 100px;
          }
          .intro-text {
            font-size: 22px;
          }
        }
      }
    }

app_component.css
    .container{
    }
    html{
      margin:auto;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: Please include your code, otherwise it's literally impossible to say what's wrong with it.

Comment: Added the code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set the body margin to auto
https://jsfiddle.net/wxmsud1d/

```
body {
  margin:auto;
}
header {
  background-color:red;
}

<header>Text goes here</header>
```

Comment: Tried it, doesn't seem to work.  Should I have this in the app component style.css or the sub component style?